# sonarqube windows begin end NG TS lint

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm having trouble combining sonarqube with Typescript Lint (run, e.g., via ng lint) under Windows (locally and in a TFS build, but I'd like to start with locally, where testing is easier.)

I tried using

SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin ...
  ng lint
  SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end

without success. Searching some more I got the idea perhaps I should be using the "preprocessor" I find in the same directory, however this appears to be too old for my C# plug-in(?)

...sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarQube.MSBuild.PreProcessor.exe /h
  *** Upgrade required ***  You are running a pre-release version of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild which is not compatible with the installed C# plugin. Please upgrade to the latest version of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild (formerly known as the MSBuild SonarQube Runner).

Am I on the right track? Do I need a newer PreProcessor? Older C# plugin? (I don't even need C# in this context.)